# Static final value assigned from companion object not allowed in annotation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I created a class in Kotlin:

```
class Extras {
    companion object {
        var EXTRA_NAME: String? = null

        fun setExtraName() {
           var extraName: String? = null
           //...
           EXTRA_NAME = extraName
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling `setExtraName()` in `onCreate()` of Application class.

Then passed `EXTRA_NAME` to the annotation of the method (defined in Java):

```
static final String EXTRA_NAME = Extras.Companion.getEXTRA_NAME();

@Extra(EXTRA_NAME)
void doSomething() {
}
```

However, I am getting following error:

> Attribute value must be constant

Why?

Comment: I am no expert in Kotlin, but shouldn't your `API_KEY` be a `val` to declare it effectively as `final`?

Comment: @Turing85 Above is just an example. In real case, I am doing calculations to assign value to constant which is further set in annotation.

Comment: @Turing85 Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fixing this

This compiles and works

```
annotation class Test(
    val value: String
)

object Keys {
    const val API_KEY = "AB"
}

@Test(Keys.API_KEY)
fun doSomething() {

}
```

const makes the value a [compile-time constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), which allows it to be swapped into the annotation.

## Why is this needed

As the annotations are accessible to the annotation processors before runtime, they have to be compile-time constants, which is why in Kotlin they have to be defined using const.

Comment: While this fixes the problem, it does not answer the question as to why OP's solution does not work.

Comment: @Turing85 I have added some explanation

Comment: Thank you for answering @jrtapsell. However, what if the value to be swapped to the annotation is not a `const`. Please check updated question.

Comment: To change an annotation at runtime needs a lot of reflection [[info](http://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params)], and is likely to be very fragile

Comment: Good answer! :)